# Ordering Points along line on QGIS

Tags: qgis

I work actually on Network Detection. Precisely, I am detecting public light electric cables undergound and drawing a map with lines connected on GPS points. Each of these points gets XYZ, and the depth of the cable, according to surface altitude.

For quality control, I have to check if there isn't more than 35 cm between to points, because it means that the detection accuracy isn't good enough.

My complete plan on QGIS look like this (fictional exemple) :

[image]

Currently, i check visually if there isn't a 35 cm depth gap between two points. I would like to make a model builder that could check automatically.

I need to make QGIS understand that he must calculate (A depth - B depth) then (B depth - C depth) ect ect... in that specific order.
It implies to make it understand he has to follow the points along the line in the start/end order.

I cannot follow XY because here there is only one line but it's an exception. Generally, there's a lot of lines that cuts or follow themselves so it's a big mess.

I ran out of idea. I checked others topics about a similar subjects but couldn't find an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Check the QGIS function `line_locate_point(geometry,point)`, it will return the distance from the line start point, you have just to order point from the min distance to max distance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried to use this function but I can't manage to make it work. 

I think it should be wrote like this :

line_locate_point (geometry(get_feature('cables','id','0')), $geometry)

But doesn't give any result, only null

Comment: I think the type of the `id` field is integer, so, the formula is : `line_locate_point (geometry(get_feature('cables', 'id', 0)), $geometry)`.

Comment: All right, I'm on the field actually so I'll tell you if it work when I'll have time to try.